# Launching HTML/Js code in browser from sublime text 2

Tags: javascript, html, text

This is probably a really newb question, but I'm trying to learn javascript, and I am very experienced in sublime text and would prefer to use that as my text editor. In this tutorial video, 
http://youtu.be/yQaAGmHNn9s?t=3m24s
 He launches his html/js code straight from notepad++. Is it possible to do this from sublime text, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods.

### [View In Browser (Plugin)](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/View%20In%20Browser)

Use this shortcuts to preview your current file in the browser (More informations and documention on the [plugin page](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/View%20In%20Browser)). The plugin also works for html pages etc.

```
CTRL + ALT + F - Firefox
CTRL + ALT + C - Chrome
CTRL + ALT + I - Internet Explorer
CTRL + ALT + S - Safari
```

### [JsRun (Plugin)](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsRun)

With this plugin you can run JavaScript code instantaneous in a browser by using

```
ALT + SUPER + J
```

where super is either Ctrl (Windows) or Cmd (Mac).
Of course you can change the keybindings.

That's all the useful plugins that i found. Note that I found them with the Sublime Text Package Manager ["Package Control"](https://packagecontrol.io/) with which you can install all kind of plugins.

### Build system

In Sublime Text you can create your own build systems. For example you can tell sublime Text to launch a browser and open a file if the build command (or keyboardshortcut `Ctrl+B`) is ran.
[Here](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/set-up-sublime-text-to-preview-your-code-in-a-web-browser/#method-2-create-a-build-system) is a tutorial in which is explained how you create a build system for your purpose.